# Calculating if an higher ranked class was offered and booked

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve following issue - and sorry if i'm drawing out too much:

A Flight Booking Platform is asking for prices on a Price Calculation Engine and its passing all necessary information to come up with prices for various options. Technically the Platform is asking for various combination of Routes (direct indirect flights, 1,2,3...stops ect.) so we will have many variants of Request ID and Route. There can be multiple requests per customer for same conditions until its booked.

The Booking Platform will - whenever it's asking for route prices - try to offer an higher class (only if available) to the customer - therefore it will do another price call within 0-5s but with a different class.

I know which values are from the higher classes e.g. U,  others are just normal classes:e.g. I

I'm looking for a sql query to find out if an higher class was offered (within the next 5s) and if the customer booked the higher class - basically enhance the booking table and add "upselling offered" , "upselling realized".

"upselling offered" -> If there is an request for the same customer, origin, destination and date +-(5s) but the class is different than "yes" (higher class was available) if not "no".

"upselling upselling realized" -> If the customer asked for a lower class but then booked the upselling offer

There could be cases where no higher class was available - so in this case there would be only one class for that combination of Customer, Origin ect..

Table i'm looking for should look like:

```
request_id  route   customer    origin  destination req_date                class   price   booked_request_id   selected_route  upselling_offered   upselling_realized
124         2       c           a       b           2000-01-01 00:00:02.000 I       22      124                 2               yes                 no
128         1       c           a       b           2000-01-05 00:00:03.000 U       24      128                 1               yes                 yes
129         2       c           a       b           2000-01-05 00:00:08.000 I       23      129                 2               no                  no
```

SQL for Values with the booking table:

```
with rr as (
select 123 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as req_date,'I' as class ,17 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 123 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as req_date,'I' as class ,20 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,19 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,22 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,25 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 125 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:06') as req_date,'U' as class ,26 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 125 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:06') as req_date,'U' as class ,27 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,24 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,28 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,23 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 127 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,22 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 127 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,26 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 128 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'U' as class ,29 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 128 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'U' as class ,24 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 129 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-02-08 00:00:08') as req_date,'I' as class ,23 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 129 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-02-08 00:00:08') as req_date,'I' as class ,26 as price ,'normal request' as explanation 
),
bookings as (
select 124 as booked_request_id, 2 as selected_route union all
select 128 as booked_request_id, 1 as selected_route union all
select 129 as booked_request_id, 2 as selected_route
)


--select req_date, class, lead(req_date) over (partition by customer,origin, destination, class order by req_date )  
--from rr left join bookings
--  on rr.request_id = bookings.booked_request_id 
--      and rr.route = bookings.selected_route
--order by class,req_date


    select req_date, request_id, route, class, 
    case when class = 'I' then
            case when   
                lead(req_date) over (partition by customer,origin, destination, class, req_date order by req_date )  <= dateadd(second, 5, req_date)
            and lead(class) over (partition by customer,origin, destination, class, req_date order by req_date )  <> class
            then 'Yes' else 'No' end    
    when class = 'U' then 
                case when   
                lag(req_date) over (partition by customer,origin, destination, class, req_date order by req_date )  >= dateadd(second, -5, req_date)
            and lag(class) over (partition by customer,origin, destination, class, req_date order by req_date )  <> class
            then 'Yes' else 'No' end    
    end as upselling_offered

    from rr left join bookings
    on rr.request_id = bookings.booked_request_id 
        and rr.route = bookings.selected_route
    order by req_date
```

Unfortunately my query doies not give the desired result - any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a select that looks for the same customer, for the same route,

```
WHERE customer = {customer}
  AND price > {previous booked price} 
  AND class > {previous booked class} 
  AND req_date > {previous_req_date}
  AND req_date <= {previous_req_date + 5 secs} 
  AND upselling_offered = yes 
  AND upselling_realized = yes
```

The items in brackets are values you would code into your query request.
Also I recommend an index on customer, req_date, upselling_offered and upselling_realized.

If this does not answer your question, I may not be fully understanding what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: upselling_offered and upselling realized is exactly what i am looking for. How would you determine it?

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i have solved it - thanks. My issue was that in the window function i grouped by class which gave me the wrong window to look for the lead/lag value...

Here is the solution:

```
with rr as (
select 123 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as req_date,'I' as class ,17 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 123 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as req_date,'I' as class ,20 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,19 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,22 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 124 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:02') as req_date,'I' as class ,25 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 125 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:06') as req_date,'U' as class ,26 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 125 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-01 00:00:06') as req_date,'U' as class ,27 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,24 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,28 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 126 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-03 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,23 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 127 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,22 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 127 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'I' as class ,26 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 128 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'U' as class ,29 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 128 as request_id, 1 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-01-05 00:00:03') as req_date,'U' as class ,24 as price ,'uselling offer' as explanation union all
select 129 as request_id, 2 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-02-08 00:00:08') as req_date,'I' as class ,23 as price ,'normal request' as explanation union all
select 129 as request_id, 3 as route, 'c' as customer, 'a' as origin, 'b' AS destination, convert(datetime, '2000-02-08 00:00:08') as req_date,'I' as class ,26 as price ,'normal request' as explanation 
),
bookings as (
select 124 as booked_request_id, 2 as selected_route union all
select 128 as booked_request_id, 1 as selected_route union all
select 129 as booked_request_id, 2 as selected_route
),

upsell_table as (
select request_id, max(upselling_offered) as upselling, class from
( select req_date, request_id, route, class, 
    --lead(req_date) over (partition by customer,origin, destination order by req_date asc) AS lead_date,
    --lead(class) over (partition by customer,origin, destination order by req_date asc) AS lead_class,
    case when class = 'I' then
            case when   
                lead(req_date) over (partition by customer,origin, destination order by req_date asc)  <= dateadd(second, 5, req_date)
            and lead(class) over (partition by customer,origin, destination  order by req_date asc)  <> class
            then 1 else 0 end   
    when class = 'U' then 
                case when   
                lag(req_date) over (partition by customer, origin, destination order by req_date )  >= dateadd(second, -5, req_date)
            and lag(class) over (partition by customer, origin, destination order by req_date )  <> class
            then 1 else 0 end   
    end as upselling_offered

    from rr left join bookings
    on rr.request_id = bookings.booked_request_id 
        and rr.route = bookings.selected_route
) T1 
group by request_id, class 
)
select booked_request_id, selected_route, 
     case when upselling = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'upselling_offered'
    ,case when upselling = 1 and T1.class = 'U' then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'upselling_successfull'
from upsell_table T1  join bookings 
    on request_id = bookings.booked_request_id
```